# Parsing Arabic date in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I ran into a problem parsing dates, the program got tripped up by Arabic dates. For some reason `DateTime.TryParse()` outputs garbage for this culture. Here is example code that illustrates my problem:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar");

DateTime date;

if (DateTime.TryParse(
    "15/01/16",
    culture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("TryParse with Arabic culture: " + date);
}

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "15/01/16",
    culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, // dd/MM/yy
    culture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("TryParseExact with Arabic short date pattern and culture: " + date);
}

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "15/01/16",
    culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, // dd/MM/yy
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("TryParseExact with Arabic short date pattern and invariant culture: " + date);
}
```

The output is this:

```
TryParse with Arabic culture: 1995-06-13 00:00:00
TryParseExact with Arabic short date pattern and culture: 1995-06-13 00:00:00
TryParseExact with Arabic short date pattern and invariant culture: 2016-01-15 00:00:00
```

Only the last version works, and I can't figure out why the first two versions fail. I could understand `TryParse` failing because it couldn't figure out which pattern to use; but in `TryParseExact` I specify the exact format, and it still fails to parse properly. I can't figure out why this happens.

Comment: Default arabic culture date time is not using Gregorian calendar IMO. What is the value for `culture.Calendar`?

Comment: @Irshad: You might want to add that as an answer, with a bit more information...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. Added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third one actually not arabic. it's a culture-insensitive culture which can be always use in any .NET application. That's why it's returning the current datetime value in `TryParseExact`. [Refer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Arabic culture not using the Gregorian calendar for it's default calendar. It's using the Lunar calendar (UmAlQuraCalendar). So your date is considered as lunar date and converted back to Gregorian.

Comment: Ah, thanks, this makes sense. I didn't know that CultureInfo could specify different calendars altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Irshads' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34742452/447156) is quite correct, I just wanna get more deep if you guys let me..

`ar` culture uses [`UmAlQuraCalendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.umalquracalendar.aspx) as `.Calendar` property not `GregorianCalendar`.

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar").Calendar.Dump();
```

[image]

That means, when you parse your string in first two example, your `16` as interpated as `1416` since this `UmAlQuraCalendar` uses `1451` as a [`TwoDigitYearMax` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx).

Since this `UmAlQuraCalendar` class is *nearly* identical to the `HijriCalendar` class, from that link http://www.islamicfinder.org/dateConversion.php?mode=hij-ger&day=15&month=1&year=1416&date_result=1

This `15/01/1416` converted as `14/06/1995` but also says;

> *There is a small probability of one day error.

So I think it is *too* normal to see `1995-06-13` as a result.

But in your third example, since `InvariantCulture` uses `GregorianCalendar`, there would be no conversation and it prints exactly what it's values.